# Set vertical Android Toolbar

Tags: android, toolbar, vertical-alignment, android-toolbar

I'm currently creating an Android application which contain a ToolBar moved to the bottom of the screen to act as a "switching scene" menu.

You can see the result on the right bottom of this [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AitMt.jpg)

What I wanted to do is to adapt the ToolBar to display it vertically on the bottom right side (instead of horizontally) like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NizCC.jpg).

ToolBar code:

```xml
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/menuToolbar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="15dp"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

Then I call initToolbar() in my OnCreate() method.

```java
private void initToolbar() {
    Toolbar toolbarBottom = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.menuToolbar);
    toolbarBottom.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new Toolbar.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
            switch(item.getItemId()){
                case R.id.action_addPoi:
                    Intent addPoi = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AddPoi.class);
                    startActivity(addPoi);
                    break;
                case R.id.action_calendar:
                    Intent calen = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Calendar.class);
                    startActivity(calen);
                    break;
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
    // Inflate a menu to be displayed in the toolbar
    toolbarBottom.inflateMenu(R.menu.menumain);
}
```

Comment: Did you try to simply rotate view in xml?

Comment: try rotation in xml

Comment: That's a good idea, unfortunately a part of the toolbar goes out of the screen... I'll try to fix it with some margin but I'm scared that doesn't fit all screen sizes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Ekalips and Warlock I managed to deal with it.

Just added

```
android:rotation="270"
android:layout_marginBottom="90dp"
android:layout_marginRight="-95dp"
```

to the first file I gave.
Result [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B88J3P1PEL0HNXJSckNzejRDNTA).

Thanks! :)